# jquery menu and xml data

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a menu and on change function I want to pull a xml field based on what is selected in the menu. I think I am on the right path, just need some tweaking. So depending on what the user selects, the kxoi id field will be appended to the dataresults. The  kxoi id  field consist of other info and the id can range from 1 - 10 . Will I have a function for each possible appending or will there just be one function with if statements nested in it? or do I put the function inside of the menu?   carSearchResult($(xData.responseXML));

```js
carSearchResult($(xData.responseXML));

function carSearchResult(xmlDoc) {
  var valueToMatch = '1';

  $(xmlDoc).MyFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

    var curItem = $(this);

    if (curItem.attr('owsID') == "1" || curItem.attr('ows_kxoi') == "1") {

      // add to result
      $("#dataresults").append(curItem.attr('ows_kxoi'));
    }

  });
  
  $(xmlDoc).MyFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

    var curItem = $(this);

    if (curItem.attr('owsID') == "2" || curItem.attr('ows_kxoi') == "2") {

      // add to result
      $("#dataresults").append(curItem.attr('ows_kxoi'));
    }

  });
}

$("#MENU").on("change", function() {
  
    var Xchange = $("#MENU :selected").val();

  if (Xchange == "0" && valueToMatch = '1') {
    alert("zero");
     $("#dataresults").append(curItem.attr('ows_kxoi'));
    }
  else if (Xchange == "2" && valueToMatch = '2';) {
    alert("2zero");
     $("#dataresults").append(curItem.attr('ows_kxoi'));
    }

});
```

```css
#results {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="MENU">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<BR>
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Can't pull the data on change